# Pagination for product reviews - SEO perspective

Tags: seo

On Magento, when a product page has a lot of reviews (let's say 100), it would be nice to paginate the reviews. This way, users can click on the next page if they would like to read more reviews.

While it is possible to add pagination to reviews on a product page, I was wondering if you guys have any opinions on this topic specifically regarding SEO implications.

Ideally, I would want to index a 'view all reviews' link and display few reviews on a product page, with pagination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [rel=”next” and rel=”prev”](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html) link elements could be the solution to this:

> Much like rel=”canonical” acts a strong hint for duplicate content, you can now use the HTML link elements rel=”next” and rel=”prev” to indicate the relationship between component URLs in a paginated series. Throughout the web, a paginated series of content may take many shapes—it can be an article divided into several component pages, or a product category with items spread across several pages, or a forum thread divided into a sequence of URLs

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html

Answer (score 0):

There wont a duplicate content issue as Google is smart enough. However you need to transfer the link juice to 1 URL using canonical tags. By doing this all the ranking / backlink juice of different variations of one URL will be transferred on one Main URL.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en